# Passing two models data which have Foreign key relationship to one html Template

Tags: python, django

I have two models. First one is Cars second one is Rating. I have list view, I am showing all cars here and I want to show cars average rating and rating count also.

I have tried adding new fields (avg_rating and rating_count) to my cars model and updating these fields while new rating was submitted. But it is not seen me as good way.

**Cars Model**

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Rating Model**

```
class RatingModel(models.Model):
    reviewed_item = models.ForeignKey(
        Cars,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    excellent = models.FloatField(
        max_length=20,
        default=0
    )...
    bad = models.FloatField(
        max_length=20,
        default=0
    )
```

**cars view**

```
class CarsView(BaseContext, TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/all_cars.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CarsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["cars"] = Cars.objects.all().order_by("-id")

        return context
```

Comment: What are `excellent` and `bad` here?

Comment: everytime user has submitted new rating I increment these fields.

Comment: but then how do you keep track of what user submitted what review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to assign a score to the `Rating` model, like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Rating(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can annotate the `queryset`. Since you basically here want to list items, a `Listview` is probably a better base view, since it will reduce the amount of boilerplate code you have to implement yourself:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Count
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class CarsView(BaseContext, ListView):
    template_name = "pages/all_cars.html"
    queryset = Cars.objects.annotate(
        avg_rating=Avg('rating__score'),
        rating_count=Count('rating')
    ).order_by('-id')
    context_object_name = 'cars'
```

The `Car` objects that arise from this queryset will have two extra attributes `.avg_rating` and `.rating_count` that will contain the average score and the number of *related* `Rating` objects.

> **Note**: The name of Django models is usually *singular* and *without* a `Model` suffix, so `Car` instead of <s>`Cars`</s>, and `Rating` instead of <s>`RatingModel`</s>.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do so will to use [aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
Cars.objects.annotate(Avg('rating'))
```

which implies that you have `rating` field that is integer, instead of excellent/bad fields.